# What on Earth is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

Found in a field near Braga, Portugal in October 2018.

[image]

Comment: It does not look like a fungus.  It looks like an insect nest - possibly a bumble bee. Did you dig this out of the ground?

Comment: Found on the ground. May have been dug up by foraging fox?  Possibly a bee or wasp nuc. Interesting!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because without a scale bar, it's impossible to know how large the object in the photo is.

Comment: I agree that the OP should provide a scale, but I wouldn't say it's impossible to know -- look at the debris in the picture. Regardless, @Corvus, please add an approximate size of your specimen (perhaps size of each sphere) to avoid having your question closed and to aid someone in providing a good answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OK, It does **not** look like a fungus. just going by the single close up photo - I'm pretty sure it is an abandoned bumblebee nest (or that of some similar social insect).  These bees often nest out of sight under logs or under the ground. Below is a link that may help you with a positive identification. I hope this provides at least a hint. Maybe you can fill in the blanks from your knowledge of your local fauna in Portugal.

http://www.bumblebee.org/lifeCcolDev.htm